# SQL query: Dynamics of the number of registrations to the previous day in percent

Tags: sql, sqlite

Name table - **Table_Users**

**User_id** - Serial number of the user

**Date_Reg** - User registration date (format - 01.05.2020)

This request only counts users, I can't figure it out

```
select
  day,
  UserCount,
  100.0 * UserCount
        / lag(UserCount) over (order by day asc)
        - 100
        AS Growth_Percentage
from
(
  SELECT strftime('%d',Date_Reg) AS day,
         COUNT(User_id) UserCount
  FROM Table_Users
  GROUP BY day
  ORDER BY day DESC
) sq
```

Is there any other query I may use?

Comment: Use for what?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you must change the format of the column `Date_Reg` to `YYYY-MM-DD`, because the format `DD.MM.YYYY` is not comparable.
Then, there is no need for a subquery.
You can use window function `LAG()` directly in your query that counts the number of users of each day:

```
SELECT Date_Reg,
       100.0 * COUNT(*) / LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY Date_Reg) - 100 AS Growth_Percentage
FROM Table_Users
GROUP BY Date_Reg
```